# How can I get rid of the extra solution while showing when equality occurs in the triangle inequality in $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

I need to come up with when equality arises in the triangle inequality and then prove it. I've come up with $|x| + |y| = |x+y|$ iff $|xy| = xy$. I have no problem proving the statement left to right ($\to$) but in the other direction ($\leftarrow$) I'm not sure what to do with the extra solution I get.

Here is where it comes up:

We want to show if $|xy|=xy$ then, $|x| + |y| = |x+y|$.

$|xy|=xy$

$2|xy|=2xy$

$|x|^2 + 2|xy| + |y|^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$

$(|x| + |y|)^2 = (x + y)^2$

$\sqrt{(|x| + |y|)^2} = \sqrt{(x + y)^2}$

$|x| + |y| = \pm(x + y)$

What do I do with $-(x+y)$? Is there anyway I can get rid of it?

Comment: Your LHS is the sum of two non-negative real numbers, so is non-negative. I think it would help if you called this triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$, as your condition is false for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: It’s always the case that for any real number $r$, $\sqrt{r^2}=|r|$, so your last step can finish the proof instead of yielding a $\pm$ sign.

Comment: Foolish of me to forget thank you! @Steve Kass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot conclude that $ a = b$ given $a^2 = b^2$ unless you can show by other means that $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. So there is no general way to get rid of the second possibility when taking the square root of a square.

But for your problem there's a better approach. You should be able to argue without much or any algebra that $|xy| = xy$ just when $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. Then use that to prove what you want.